# How to get same instance using lombok

Tags: java, lombok

How to get the same instance in Lombok

for example

```
class A {
    int x;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A o1 = new A();
        A o2 = o1;
        System.out.println(o1 == o2); //true
    }
}
```

And I want to know how can I achieve this using Lombok

Comment: `Lombok` is a code generation library. You could maybe use `@Singleton` lombok annotation as a workaround ...

Comment: Your example makes no sense. It does already what you want in the simplest possible way, no neither Lombok nor anything else can help you. Post a better exaple.